# How Can I Not Show the Green Download Progress Display for Google Chrome in the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, download, taskbar

I use Windows 7 and when downloading with Google Chrome, the icon in the taskbar has a partially green background that indicates the download progress.
Is there a way to not show this green status indicator in the Windows taskbar?

I do not want to hide the icon entirely but rather just not show the green background.
I have searched for an option or setting to change this but there seems to be surprisingly little information about this on the Internet.

Comment: as far as i can tell there is no way to disable that feature, it is part of the change google made to the download ui a couple of years back.

Comment: you can use an external download manager

Comment: If you set the taskbar color (see also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1558106/color-of-active-window-in-windows-10-taskbar/1558107#1558107)) to the same green color, the green color of the download might become quite unnoticeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Community Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-disable-the-green-progress-bar-that/2717f28a-9b75-457c-926f-7a6cff8f6e9d?auth=1) members, you cannot cannot disable this Microsoft Windows feature (in the Windows settings at least).

> the program gets to control this in the same way that the program gets to control the name of it's title bar.  If the program tells the taskbar to show progress, the Taskbar will obey.

This means that if Google Chrome were to provide an "off switch" for this feature, then this would totally be possible; "if the program tells the taskbar to show progress, the Taskbar will obey", therefore it the program (Google Chrome) tells the taskbar **not** to show the progress, then the taskbar will obey (and **not** show the progress).

In the [Google Chrome Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/0ZZcEncN0H0), people have already decided to discuss the issue and have gotten nowhere. Despite the old forum timeline, Google still has not implemented a solution to disable it.

From my research, this is not possible. Sorry for the bad news.