# Color of active window in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, colors

In the Windows 10 taskbar, the active window is not very strongly highlighted. This makes it difficult to quickly see which window is active. How can I change the color of the active window?

Related questions:

- [Change taskbar hover/selection color Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1465009/change-taskbar-hover-selection-color-windows-10)
- [windows 10 - make taskbar itself a different color from the taskbar buttons](https://superuser.com/questions/1073441/windows-10-make-taskbar-itself-a-different-color-from-the-taskbar-buttons)

Comment: I use a workaround detailed in this answer:
[Classic Shell approach](https://superuser.com/questions/1717690/make-active-window-more-obvious-on-taskbar-windows-10/1758928#1758928)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AccentPaletteTool](https://github.com/Raymai97/AccentPaletteTool/releases) or [Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/winaero-tweaker/) can be tried, but I haven't checked whether it provides a full solution. A full solution without using a tool is this:

- Go to Settings → Personalization → Colors. Enable "show color on Start, taskbar and action center". ([If it is greyed out, change from the light mode to the dark mode](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/start-taskbar-action-center-greyed-out.html#start,-taskbar,-and-action-center-greyed-out-1131). You can still customize most colors to be light or whatever you want.)
- Open the Registry Editor
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent\AccentPalette`
- Set the entries 10,11,12 of `AccentPalette` to the [web color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) you want. (If taskbar transparency is enabled, then maybe other entries than 10,11,12 should be changed.) (Some entries were explained in a discussion on Reddit [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/3fdwo5/how_to_change_your_accent_color_to_anything_you/ctnujt5/?context=3).)
- To solve [the problem that "it affects many places"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/highlight-active-window-in-task-bar-windows-10/9e4b6b34-11c8-4bd6-b4ee-21a06fc56180?fbclid=IwAR0YG6GBm1xKdAQTEX4Dtb1osapUf4QSbL_alfWQ3dj73x_JUXW0YQZoFsw): set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\ColorPrevalence` to the value `2`

Result:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thanks, I tried https://github.com/Raymai97/AccentPaletteTool ,it work! it is  a good GUI tool to change AccentPalette , after run it, you will see 8 colors, you need change 5th color, and then click "Restart Explorer";   if you want to change  AccentPalette  manually, for example, "AccentPalette"=hex:c1,f7,dd,00,a6,f7,d0,00,68,e3,a8,00,00,cc,6a,00,00,a2,28, 00,00,52,2a,00,00,2b,16,00,e3,00,8c,00   , you need to change "00,a2,28" (RGB 0,162,40) to other color

Comment: @qiz_newbie The 4th color has to be changed, not the 5th. And it seems that AccentPaletteTool alone doesn't do the trick, and the first step of my answer is additionally necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. A bit confusing though, I had to restart session multiple times to figure it out. Basically nothing has changed since the reddit post. There're still 8 color components 4 bytes each. So I needed 5th and 6th to change the active taskbar button and the whole taskbar colors respectively. To highlight active window with light gray color on dark gray taskbar I used: 55 55 55 00 22 22 22 00. Basically you meant the bytes hex addresses 10 to 12, not "entries", so it's correct at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Windows 10 users are out of luck as Microsoft has disabled
taskbar button skinning based on themes (visual styles).

Also, as Windows 10 constantly keeps changing, a theme will not work for long and
major updates will break it.