# How can I make the windows 10 taskbar window icon highlight the entire tile instead of just a thin strip?

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors, desktop-customization

By default, when a window is open, you can only see a thin 2 pixel bar on the side of the icon as you can see with firefox.

I want it to show a background color at all times like with the itunes icon (in the image, it is hovered).

How can I change the color so that it has a different background color when a window is open so that it is easier to see?

[image]

Comment: See if this SU answer helps:  https://superuser.com/questions/1558106/color-of-active-window-in-windows-10-taskbar   ...  Not a native feature of Windows 10 or 11.

Comment: @John that changes the active window color. I would like to change the inactive window color to something that is not transparent. Similar to the 3rd icon in my example

Comment: How do two users [`327552` | `107996`] get the exact same username and does mentioning one alert both? @John The one thing you could try is to find the ARGB/RGBA hex value in the Registry for the inactive tile and change the A[lpha] value to be more opaque and less transparent. While there should be a key for this _(even though many color options within the Registry became defunct in Windows 10 due to the full incorporation of UWP apps into the UI, transparency is usually still handled by a Registry key applying the A[lpha] channel)_, if not, third-party software would be required.